# Using a bitmask and if statement

Tags: c, switch-statement, bitmask

I am trying to allow multiple cases to run in a switch statement. I have a bitmask as follows:

```
#define SHOOT_ROCKET 2 << 16
#define MOVE_FORWARD 3 << 16
```

Later, I do

```
switch (int game_action)
```

and I have

```
case SHOOT_ROCKET:
  result = fire_weapon(rl);
```

I don't want to 'break', because I want possibility of multiple actions. But I am returning a value called 'result'. I store this as a variable and return at the end. I can tell other case: statements are running though even when they shouldn't because result keeps getting changed and doesn't if I add break;

What is the best way to deal with this?

**Update**: I've been told to do if instead.

I changed my << bitmasks so they start at 1 now.

I am experiencing a weird bug

```
if (game_action->action & SHOOT_ROCKET)
{
    game_action->data=5;
}
if (game_action->action & MOVE_FORWARD)
 {
    game_action->data=64;
}
```

I am not concerned about game_action being overwritten when I intend for multiple if's to evaluate to true

However: it seems MOVE_FORWARD is happening even if I only try and shoot a rocket!

game_action is a void pointer normally, so this is how it's setup in the function:

```
game_action = (game_action) *game_action_ptr;
```

I have verified the bitmask is correct with

```
printf("%d", game_action->action >> 16) which prints 2.
```

So why is '3' (the move forward) happening when I am only trying to shoot a rocket?

Comment: `SHOOT_ROCKET 0 << 16` is `0`.  Is that your intention?

Comment: Probably need `result` to be an array.

Comment: > What is the best way to deal with this? <  Use `if(game_action & SHOOT_ROCKET) { ... }`.

Comment: Or make `result` a bitmask like `game_action`.

Comment: If you use `switch` the case will only be hit if it is the exact value, not if a particular bit is set.

Comment: >
 
If you use switch the case will only be hit if it is the exact value

Then why is it firing multiple times at the moment?

Comment: `switch` statements fall through until they hit a `break` or the end of the `switch`.

Comment: Post the `switch` statement in a context we can understand.

Comment: Why do you have the `int` type declaration inside the `switch()` statement? The type declaration should be where you create the variable.

Comment: I have changed to if ( &) now and removed the (int) cast. I am having an issue where it is triggered twice however still.

Comment: You need to use break to stop it once you've executed the code for a particular case or it will continue to execute until it hits a break or the end of the switch is reached.

Comment: I will update my question. This is no longer about switch

Comment: Updated the question above

Comment: You need mutually exclusive bits to do what you want.  2 and 3 overlap and the way you are testing is asking if any bits are set as the result, not if it actually matches what you're looking for.  `if(&game_action->action & MOVE_FORWARD) == MOVE_FORWARD)` might get you a bit farther, but fixing the bit values would be a better idea.

Comment: to make them mutually exclusive, should i do 2, 4, 8, instead of 1,2,3,4?

Comment: `#define SHOOT_ROCKET 2 << 16` -->> `#define SHOOT_ROCKET (1u << 17)`

Answer (score 0):

Please do update your question.

> So why is '3' (the move forward) happening when I am only trying to shoot a rocket?

The first thing you want to look at is

```
#define SHOOT_ROCKET 2 << 16
#define MOVE_FORWARD 3 << 16
```

and think what that evaluates to. It will evaluate to the following binary numbers (Python is handy for this kind of stuff, `0b` is just a prefix that means binary is following):

```
>>> bin(2 << 16)
'0b100000000000000000'
>>> bin(3 << 16)
'0b110000000000000000'
```

So you see that you use one bit twice in your `#define`s (Retired Ninja already pointed this out). This means that if `game_action->action` is set to anything where the bit `2 << 16` is `1`, both of your ifs will evaluate to true, because both `#define`s have that bit set to `1`.

> to make them mutually exclusive, should i do 2, 4, 8, instead of 1,2,3,4?

If you want to easily keep track of which bits are used, you can either use powers of two (1,2,4,8,16, etc), e.g. `#define MOVE_FORWARD 4` (I'm ignoring the `<< 16` you have, you can add that if you want), or you can shift a `1` by a variable number of bits, both result in the same binary numbers:

```
#define MOVE_LEFT 1 << 0
#define MOVE_RIGHT 1 << 1
#define MOVE_UP 1 << 3
#define MOVE_DOWN 1 << 4
```

There are legitimate cases where bitmasks need to have more than one bit set, for example for checking if any one of several bits are set:

```
#define MOVE_LEFT ... (as above)
#define SHOOT_ROCKET 1 << 5
#define SHOOT_GUN 1 << 6
//...
#define ANY_MOVEMENT 0xF
#define ANY_WEAPON_USE 0xF << 4
```

and then check:

```
if (action & ANY_MOVEMENT) { ... }
if (action & ANY_WEAPON_USE) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

place parens '(' ')' around the value part (2<<15) kind of values so there is no errors introduced by the text replacement.

I.E. this:

```
'if( (&game_action->action & MOVE_FORWARD) == MOVE_FORWARD)'
```

becomes

```
'if( (&game_action->action & 2 << 16) == 2 << 16)'
```

Note the posted code is missing a left paren, which I added.

Where the '&' has a higher Precedence the '<<' so it (effectively) becomes

```
'if( ( (&game_action->action & 2) << 16) == 2 << 16)'
```

where the '&' is done to the 2 and not to the 2<<16